# How to maintain data of five activities when comes to First activity on click of back in fifth Activity

Tags: android

I am writing a application where I am dealing with 5 activities, let's say A, B, C , D & E.
 Activity A invokes B, B invokes C, C invokes D,D invokes E. On each of the activity, I have a button called "next" button and editText to fill name. When user clicks on next button in any of the A,B, C, D,E activities, application should go  to next  activity screen but when user clicks On back button in E activity it should go on activity A.

Now my question is when i start from activity A after coming from activty E on back press  I want to maintain data of editText of all the actvities which filled by user when comes first time ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Have a Shared Preference file. When clicking next you save the fields in your shared preference.

then when loading a activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
loadSavedPreferences(); 

}
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

et1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("string_et_Name",""));

}
```

Have your own saving mechanism on the next button click.

Note: Clear your shared preference when clicking finish (if required)

Comment: don't want to use shared preference.Is there any other way to do this

Comment: use *SQLITE* than

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:** decalre a boolean flag with int value on MainActivity first suppose:

```
private boolean flag=200;
```

**step 2:** from main activity we are switching to suppose 5 other activities on a button click respectively.
So from main activity we call `StartActivityForResult(intent,flag);` which indicate that we can come back with the same flag value from any activity.

**step 3:** now suppose we want data of activity "E" (as per your question) then we send it by sending it through bundle;
like:       declare same boolean value of 200 on each activity from which we are traveling

```
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("firstName",firstName);
                intent.putExtra("lastName",lastName);
                setResult(flag,intent);
                finish();
```

**step 4:** get bundle vale on coming activities by `onActivityResult()` method which is overriden
and check with flag value
like:

```
        if (resultCode==200)
        {
            String firstName=data.getStringExtra("firstName");
            String lastName=data.getStringExtra("lastName");

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("firstName",firstName);
            intent.putExtra("lastName",lastName);
            setResult(200,intent);
            finish();
        }
```

**step 5:** similarly for all activities;

**step 6:** finally, get bundle on MainActivity 
like:

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode==200)
        {
            String firstName=data.getStringExtra("firstName");
            String lastName=data.getStringExtra("lastName");

            textViewFirstName.setText(firstName);
            textViewLastName.setText(lastName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to your needs and like you i started with activities but then I found this, which makes all easy, 1 activity with several fragments instead of lots of activities, maybe you are interested in : [StepStone](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper)

Here the answers to common questions : [ans](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed)

Then if you want to pass data, i am working with Parceler because i saved my data in custom classes, check my question:
[How can i correctly interact between Activities and fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062320/how-can-i-correctly-interact-between-activities-and-fragments)

If you have any doubts just say it.
Hope this helps!