# How to prevent passing data to multiple activities through intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity A that passes data to activity B through Intent. Now Activity B calls Activity C and Activity C calls Activity D. Now Activity D is calling activity B. Now activity B check for the intent data but the Activity D doesn't pass any data.

Now one way to do this is to pass data through C and D and finally get it in B but i would like to know if there is a better way to handle this ?

i would like to add that the data can be an object with a lot of variables and array.

Edit :- The data is necessary for activity B to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your are passing same data to many activities, Use Sharedpreference instead of intent.putextra()

Comment: Hi @ANUJ GUPTA, its simple way to store data on following manner like, 1) Use SharedPreferences 2)Store in getter setter like pojo class concept.

Comment: use can create and activity with
  `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to ActivityB then it will open again the same instance which called C

Comment: The data i am passing can be an object so Shared Preference cannot be used. Here is a link to support this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference

Comment: yes in shared preffrence you can also use objects usin library   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

Comment: save them as Global Object, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188214/how-to-maintain-data-of-five-activities-when-comes-to-first-activity-on-click-of/45188685#45188685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you are passing is different, then assign a variable (named `activity_name`) with the name of the activity that is calling the intent. In this way, you can check if you are coming to activity B from activity A or D.

Let me try to explain with an example:

**ActivityA**

```
String activity_name = "ACTIVITY_A";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("calling_activity", activity_name);
intent.putExtra("your_data", your_data); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**ActivityB**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String callingActivity = intent.getExtras().getString("calling_activity");

if (callingActivity.matches("ACTIVITY_A")) {
    // Do something
} else if (callingActivity.matches("ACTIVITY_D")) {
    // Do something else
}
```

and in **ActivityD**

```
String activity_name = "ACTIVITY_D";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("calling_activity", activity_name);
// No passed data in Actiivty D
startActivity(intent);
```

*This same logic can be employed using `SharedPreferences` as remarked in other answers and comments.*

Comment: Please check the edit the data is necessary for B to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferrence;

For storing values;

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
Ed.putString("id",login_id.getText().toString() );
Ed.putString("password",login_password.getText().toString() );
Ed.commit();
```

For getting values;

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
String uName = sharedPreferences.getString("id", "");
String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
```

Comment: Sorry but in my question the data i mentioned can be an object. Do you have a solution for that case ?

Comment: You can pass any object in replace of login_id.getText().toString() and login_password.getText().toString()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference

Answer (score 1):

You can Check Your Intent is not null and its has Extras value or not by getting Bundle and another check if Bundle oBject is not null then you check keys are there or not in Bundle Object.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 if(intent!=null)
 {
   Bundle bundle =  intent.getExtras();
   if(bundle!=null)
   {
      if(bundle.containsKey("key"))
      {
      //here you can put your code for Actvity B when comes from Activity  A.
      }
   }
 }
```

**EDIT 1**
Use singleTask launchMode in Activity B in manifest file.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: do you want data in all activiities

Comment: No i only need it in B not C & D

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson.jar to store class objects into SharedPreferences.

add GSON dependency in Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Creating a shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To save:

```
  Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(MyObject);
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

To Retrieve:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code in your activity B.

```
String str= getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

if (str == null){
str= "";
}
```

Comment: How does this responds to the OP's question?